# How does FreeBSD track files installed via ports?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

It looks like `pkg remove <pkg>` is able to remove a package installed via ports. But I didn't find any packages built by typing `make` in the ports dir. So what's the magic here? How does `pkg remove` know about the files belonging to a packge?

Comment: I don't use FreeBSD, but in OpenBSD the package database is in `/var/db/pkg` and contains all information needed for removing (etc.) packages. I'm sure this well explained in a FreeBSD manual for one of the package tools. Try `man pkg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `make install` in the ports collection registers the package to the FreeBSD package system (by creating a temporary package manifest from the port and running `pkg register`). From this the `pkg` command knows what is installed and how to remove it.

> a simple make install will install the application and register it with the package system.

[About FreeBSD Ports](https://www.freebsd.org/ports/)

It is also stated in the FreeBSD handbook that you can use pkg to remove installed ports.

> Installed ports can be uninstalled using pkg delete.

[Using the Ports Collection](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html)

Comment: @JdeBP thanks for the edit. Including the creation of temporary manifest was a good clarification.